# Incorrect page numbering with different numbering styles

Tags: numbering, page-numbering

I have an issue with my page numbering. I want the first pages of my document number in "roman" style and the rest "arabic". I have done this with the `\pagenumbering` command, which actually works quite well. The only problem is, when I switch to arabic page numbering before the chapter "Introduction" it, kind of recursively, also applies for the preceding chapter "List of Abbreviations", what should not be the case.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[a4paper, width=159mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{tablefootnote}
    \usepackage{footnote}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\input{partials/titlepage}
\chapter*{Document version}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Document version}
\input{partials/document_versions}
\chapter*{About this Document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{About this Document}
\input{partials/purpose_of_this_paper}
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\input{partials/list_of_abbreviations}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{partials/introduction}
\chapter{System}  
\input{partials/system}
\chapter{Component}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\pagenumbering` applies to the current page, so move it to just after `\chapter{Introduction}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\pagenumbering` command applies to the current page.  Issuing before `\chapter{Introduction}` means that it applies to the page you are on at that time, in this case the List of Abbreviations.  Instead you can move `\pagenumbering` it to just after `\chapter{Introduction}` to get the new numbering to start on that page.

Had you been using the `book` class instead of report, you could have used the division commands `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` to effect exactly the changes you are after.